# ¿Cómo retirar el index.php de codeigniter en un host básico?

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo un proyecto en codeigniter corriendo en un hosting básico de goodady.
El problema que tengo es el siguiente según la documentación de codeigniter, se puede retirar index.php de las urls con el siguiente código.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

La url actual a la que quiero acceder es:

```
http://www.mks.bz/proyectos/ventas_ci/index.php/welcome
```

y debería quedar así:

```
http://www.mks.bz/proyectos/ventas_ci/welcome
```

Lo he probado en modo local y funciona muy bien, pero al momento de subir a mi hosting dentro de una carpeta simplemente no funciona.

---

He verificado que el mod_rewrite esta habilitado usando el siguiente código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule prueba.html https://www.google.com.pe [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Quiero que no se muestre el index.php en las urls. http://www.mks.bz/proyectos/ventas_ci/index.php/welcome debería quedar así http://www.mks.bz/proyectos/ventas_ci/welcome

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar `index.php` de una URL, lo que se debe hacer es **redireccionar** a la URL sin el mismo. Y luego, cuando se está accediendo a un recurso que no existe, se debe **reescribir** al `index.php/url`.

```py
RewriteEngine On

# Si tiene index.php, redireccionar a URL sin index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:$|/(.*)) $1 [NC,R=302,L]

# Si no existe el recurso, reescribir al index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

> En el caso de que quieras reescribir a `index.php?/url` (con la url como parámetro de búsqueda con el `?`), se cambia la última línea por:
>
> ```py
> RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

He esta probando con diferentes configuraciones en el archivo .htaccess pero ninguna me estaba funcionando.

Así que lo que hice fue colocar el proyecto el la raíz del host y no dentro de una carpeta como lo tenia anteriormente y usar el siguiente codigo en el .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

y me soluciono el problema que tenia.

Según puede ver el problema esta en que el .htaccess solo funciona en la raíz del host mas no cuando se coloca dentro de una carpeta. Si me equivoco hacérmelo saber.

Comment: Un .htaccess puede estar en cualquier subdirectorio, y el más específico toma prcedencia sobre el root

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar ese molesto index.php se deben realizar algunas cosas

Tomemos el ejemplo de un sistema de una farmacia que yo tengo en 
localhost/farmacia

En la carpeta farmacia que es la del codeigniter crearas un archivo .htaccess y dentro de este, el siguiente codigo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Me voy a localhost/Farmacia/application\config abres el archivo "config.php" y editas la linea 26 que dice:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

y la cambias por

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Farmacia/';
```

por ultimo en el mismo archivo bajas a la linea 38 y editas:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

lo cambias por

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Y eso es todo :)